# No pueden pagar desde el exterior si no tienen cuenta de Argentina

Tags: mercadopago

quisiera informarme si alguien sabe, de como pueden abonar desde el exterior sin tener que crear una cuenta de ML en Argentina. Decidí implementar MP pero estoy teniendo quejas de cuando quieren abonar en el exterior. Es posible configurando algun parametro o poniendo USD en currency_id se pueda?

```
$preference_data = array(
    "items" => array(
       array(
           "title" => $ref_producto,
           "quantity" => 1,
           "currency_id" => "ARS",
           "unit_price" => $importe
       )
    )
);
```

Comment: se que la respuesta puede ser tonta, pero no consultaste las api de mercadopago? https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/api-docs/

Comment: Hola Sebastian, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Si, lamentablemente ya busqué alli y no encontré nada que haga referencia a esto. Me llevé una sorpresa cuando sucede que tienen que crear una cuenta en Argentina para abonar desde el exterior. No es muy lógico... o si, pero me está trayendo dificultades. Gracias igualemente!

Comment: Yo implemente mercadopago y not uve problemas desde el exterior siempre y cuando sea una tarjeta internacional (VISA, Mastercard). Obvio a vos aca la plata entra en pesos.
Saludos!